# Keyboard glitching on GTA San Andreas, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, wine, games, steam, playonlinux

When in-game my keyboard is all glitchy. On the winehq page it says,

```
Keyboard becomes glitchy when you start playing, but if you hide it once, everything works perfectly.
```

But I don't know how to do this. Please Help me to recover from the problem.